# How to use Python's win32com to "save as" an Excel file?

Tags: python, excel, win32com

I have a small Python code to open an Excel file. Now I want to "Save As" with a different name but same format.
How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Just use the `SaveAs` method:

```
import win32com.client 

office = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application") 
wb = office.Workbooks.Open("C:/FileName.xlsx") 
wb.SaveAs(Filename="C:\\NewFileName.xlsx")
wb.Close()
office.Quit()
```

Comment: Note that `office.Quit()` will close all excel instances you have open.